# problem running bash script in meson.build

Tags: bash, meson-build

I have an heder file vproj.h

```
#ifndef verVERSION
#define verVERSION "B.32.0"
#endif
```

and a bash script "getVer "to estract the version, so from cmd line

```
/home/../getVer  verVERSION vproj.h
B.32.0
```

now I want to embed it in my meson.build with run_command

```
version = run_command('getVer', 'verVERSION','vproj.h').stdout().strip()
```

but when I try co configure the proj I have the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line
> 227, in run
> return options.run_func(options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/msetup.py", line
> 281, in run
> app.generate()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/msetup.py", line
> 184, in generate
> self._generate(env)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/msetup.py", line
> 223, in _generate
> intr.run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 2476, in run
> super().run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 132, in run
> self.evaluate_codeblock(self.ast, start=1)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 157, in evaluate_codeblock
> raise e   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 150, in evaluate_codeblock
> self.evaluate_statement(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 165, in evaluate_statement
> self.assignment(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 912, in assignment
> value = self.evaluate_statement(node.value)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 179, in evaluate_statement
> return self.evaluate_arraystatement(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 215, in evaluate_arraystatement
> (arguments, kwargs) = self.reduce_arguments(cur.args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 877, in reduce_arguments
> reduced_pos: T.List[T.Union[TYPE_var, InterpreterObject]] = [self.evaluate_statement(arg) for arg in args.arguments]   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 877, in 
> reduced_pos: T.List[T.Union[TYPE_var, InterpreterObject]] = [self.evaluate_statement(arg) for arg in args.arguments]   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 163, in evaluate_statement
> return self.function_call(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 554, in function_call
> res = func(node, func_args, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 643, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 643, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 643, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   [Previous line repeated 5 more times]   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 87, in wrapped
> ret = f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 106, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 224, in wrapper
> return f(*nargs, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 1569, in func_dependency
> d = df.lookup(kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/dependencyfallbacks.py",
> line 334, in lookup
> dep = func(kwargs, func_args, func_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/dependencyfallbacks.py",
> line 122, in _do_subproject
> self.interpreter.do_subproject(subp_name, 'meson', func_kwargs)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 909, in do_subproject
> raise e   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 893, in do_subproject
> return self._do_subproject_meson(subp_name, subdir, default_options, kwargs)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 932, in _do_subproject_meson
> subi.run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 2476, in run
> super().run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 132, in run
> self.evaluate_codeblock(self.ast, start=1)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 157, in evaluate_codeblock
> raise e   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 150, in evaluate_codeblock
> self.evaluate_statement(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 165, in evaluate_statement
> self.assignment(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 912, in assignment
> value = self.evaluate_statement(node.value)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 167, in evaluate_statement
> return self.method_call(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 567, in method_call
> obj = self.evaluate_statement(invokable)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 167, in evaluate_statement
> return self.method_call(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 567, in method_call
> obj = self.evaluate_statement(invokable)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 163, in evaluate_statement
> return self.function_call(cur)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/interpreterbase.py",
> line 554, in function_call
> res = func(node, func_args, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 643, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 643, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreterbase/decorators.py",
> line 106, in wrapped
> return f(*wrapped_args, **wrapped_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 749, in func_run_command
> return self.run_command_impl(node, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreter.py",
> line 817, in run_command_impl
> in_builddir=in_builddir, check=check, capture=capture)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreterobjects.py",
> line 166, in **init**
> self.returncode, self.stdout, self.stderr = self.run_command(cmd, args, env, source_dir, build_dir, subdir, mesonintrospect,
> in_builddir, check)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/interpreter/interpreterobjects.py",
> line 198, in run_command
> p, o, e = Popen_safe(command_array, stdout=stdout, env=child_env, cwd=cwd)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mesonbuild/mesonlib/universal.py",
> line 1398, in Popen_safe
> stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/.../getVer' FAILED:
> build.ninja

What is wrong in the run_command usage?

Comment: I'm getting a similar response and all my script contains is ls. run_command('ls') works fine but not if I put it in a script. I take it you did remember to 'sudo chmod +x scriptname'?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got mine to work by inserting

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at beginning of script.

Yours works for me as well although I'm guessing as to what getVER contains.